# How to make XFCE look and feel like Unity?

Tags: unity, xfce, desktop-environments

Canonical is going to retire Unity and use Gnome as default desktop environment for Ubuntu.
I found my old system running very slow under Gnome desktop environment but it is super fast using XFCE (it is much better than Gnome under Unity).
And I still love how Unity looks like.
There are enough guides on the Internet on how to make Gnome look like Unity, but I could not find any for XFCE.

How can I make XFCE look and function as similar as possible to Unity?

---

Edit:
What we want:

1. A panel on the left side similar to [Unity launcher](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/unity-launcher-intro.html). It would be better if it had:

   1.1. A Dash button which starts something similar to [Unity Dash](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/unity-dash-intro.html). It should at least allow you to search for apps and run them (we omitted lenses).

   1.2. Launcher icons should be shown for running applications. We should be able to pin some applications hence we would be able to find and launch them easier in the future. Having a rich right-click menu is desirable.

   1.3. A show desktop button.

   1.4. A switch workspace tool.

   1.5. A show trash button. Rich right click menu is desirable.
2. Top panel similar to Unity top panel with that functionality. It should contain:

   2.1.  From right to left: Shutdown menu, Clock and calendar tool, Sound tool (with the same useful menu it have in Unity), Language tool, Network connection manager, Application notification icons.

   2.2. App menus, if possible (another option is placing app menu in window titlebar).

   2.3. Window titlebar and management buttons for maximized windows.
3. As an alternative option window titlebar should contain app menu, if possible.
4. [HUD](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/unity-hud-intro.html), if possible.
5. The same keyboard shortcuts as Unity's shortcuts.

---

If you think I missed anything important, please add it to the list.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://dasublogbyprashanth.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-make-xfce-like-unity.html)?

Comment: Best bet then is to make your own desktop out of light weight packages and use a dock. Check out some videos I did showing you how on YouTube. My username there is doriandotslash.

Comment: @AndroidDev That's really good. I could not find it before. However, I already tested the same setup on my desktop. Actually Task Bar seems buggy sometimes and I'm not satisfied with that. Let's see if we could find any better answers. We could also add that setup as an answer here to make it as another reference for users.

Comment: @Dorian Thank you about introducing your good channel. I would watch them. I'm sure they would help me a lot.
Making my own desktop is really a good idea. But the problem is it needs a lot of time -from learning to implementation. What about newbie users? Could we find an easy to implement solution for everyone?

Comment: The "look" part maybe easier, but the "feel" part requires you to specify which usability features of Unity you want to have in Xfce. To that extent, your question is incomplete.

Comment: @DKBose I've added the "What we want" part. Hope it would help.